# Stop working project with vector drawables after update build.gradle on API < 21

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-vectordrawable

I have working project.

- minSdkVersion 17
- com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3
- gradle 4.1
- Android Studio 3 Canary 6

I have in my gradle files:

```
defaultConfig {
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
        vectorDrawables.generatedDensities = []
}
```

I call in activity too:

```
AppCompatDelegate.setCompatVectorFromResourcesEnabled(true)
```

Application works perfectly. Now change to:

- com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0-alpha6
- add to repositories `google()` line

Execute `gradle clean assembleDebug`.

App continue works on devices with API > 20. But for API < 21 (google android emulator) get crash on start application.
I see in logcat error: `Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f080058` (0x7f080058 is drawable abc_vector_test).

Why?

**UPD 2017-07-19**: It was fixed and released in com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0-alpha7

Comment: You should file a bug if not already open in https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=190923

Comment: Done: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/63646848

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gradle plugin from version 3 use new AAPT, that have some bugs.
After reading some issues on bug tracker, I've found that Gradle has option for full disable AAPT2: `android.enableAapt2=false`

Also from release notes to alpha5:

> AAPT2. We are continuing to stabilize AAPT2 which enables incremental resource processing. If your build fails due to resource
>   processing issue, please send us a bug report. To temporarily disable
>   AAPT, set android.enableAapt2=false in your gradle.properties file.
>   Roboelectric is currently not compatible with AAPT2

Answer (score 8):

I'm add to `gradle.properties` line

```
android.enableAapt2=false
```

and it's solve my error.

**UPD 2017-07-19**: It was fixed and released in com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0-alpha7

Answer (score 0):

I am facing the same problem, downgrade Android Studio to previous version canary5 and write the following in your build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    ...
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0-alpha5'
    ...
```