# Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f08005e

Tags: android

I have been receiving the error `Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f08005e` only on android 4.4.

According to R.java `#0x7f08005e` translates to `public static final int abc_vector_test = 0x7f08005e;`

Below is the logcat for a test device:

```
07-14 18:16:21.427 W/dalvikvm(13338): threadid=1: thread exiting with 

uncaught exception (group=0x41572d88)
07-14 18:16:21.427 E/AndroidRuntime(13338): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-14 18:16:21.427 E/AndroidRuntime(13338): Process: za.co.GAME, PID: 13338
07-14 18:16:21.427 E/AndroidRuntime(13338): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{za.co.GAME/za.co.GAME.DashActivity}: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f08005e
07-14 18:16:21.427 E/AndroidRuntime(13338):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2248)
07-14 18:16:21.427 E/AndroidRuntime(13338):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2298)
07-14 18:16:21.427 E/AndroidRuntime(13338):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
07-14 18:16:21.427 E/AndroidRuntime(13338):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1246)
07-14 18:16:21.427 E/AndroidRuntime(13338):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
07-14 18:16:21.427 E/AndroidRuntime(13338):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:212)
07-14 18:16:21.427 E/AndroidRuntime(13338):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5151)
07-14 18:16:21.427 E/AndroidRuntime(13338):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-14 18:16:21.427 E/AndroidRuntime(13338):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
07-14 18:16:21.427 E/AndroidRuntime(13338):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:877)
07-14 18:16:21.427 E/AndroidRuntime(13338):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:693)
07-14 18:16:21.427 E/AndroidRuntime(13338):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-14 18:16:21.427 E/AndroidRuntime(13338): Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f08005e
07-14 18:16:21.427 E/AndroidRuntime(13338):     at android.content.res.Resources.getValue(Resources.java:1125)
07-14 18:16:21.427 E/AndroidRuntime(13338):     at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.loadDrawableFromDelegates(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:332)
07-14 18:16:21.427 E/AndroidRuntime(13338):     at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:197)
07-14 18:16:21.427 E/AndroidRuntime(13338):     at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:190)
07-14 18:16:21.427 E/AndroidRuntime(13338):     at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.checkVectorDrawableSetup(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:711)
07-14 18:16:21.427 E/AndroidRuntime(13338):     at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:195)
07-14 18:16:21.427 E/AndroidRuntime(13338):     at android.support.v7.widget.TintTypedArray.getDrawableIfKnown(TintTypedArray.java:81)
07-14 18:16:21.427 E/AndroidRuntime(13338):     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplBase.<init>(AppCompatDelegateImplBase.java:131)
07-14 18:16:21.427 E/AndroidRuntime(13338):     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.<init>(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:155)
07-14 18:16:21.427 E/AndroidRuntime(13338):     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV11.<init>(AppCompatDelegateImplV11.java:31)
07-14 18:16:21.427 E/AndroidRuntime(13338):     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV14.<init>(AppCompatDelegateImplV14.java:55)
07-14 18:16:21.427 E/AndroidRuntime(13338):     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegate.create(AppCompatDelegate.java:205)
07-14 18:16:21.427 E/AndroidRuntime(13338):     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegate.create(AppCompatDelegate.java:185)
07-14 18:16:21.427 E/AndroidRuntime(13338):     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.getDelegate(AppCompatActivity.java:519)
07-14 18:16:21.427 E/AndroidRuntime(13338):     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.onCreate(AppCompatActivity.java:71)
07-14 18:16:21.427 E/AndroidRuntime(13338):     at za.co.GAME.classes.SuperActivity.onCreate(SuperActivity.java:84)
07-14 18:16:21.427 E/AndroidRuntime(13338):     at za.co.GAME.DashActivity.onCreate(DashActivity.java:208)
07-14 18:16:21.427 E/AndroidRuntime(13338):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
07-14 18:16:21.427 E/AndroidRuntime(13338):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
07-14 18:16:21.427 E/AndroidRuntime(13338):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2212)
07-14 18:16:21.427 E/AndroidRuntime(13338):     ... 11 more
07-14 18:16:21.437 W/ActivityManager( 1199):   Force finishing activity za.co.GAME/.DashActivity
07-14 18:16:21.467 W/InstanceID/Rpc( 1845): Found 10029
07-14 18:16:21.477 D/dalvikvm(14115): Trying to load lib /data/app-lib/com.google.android.gms-1/libgmscore.so 0x4470dc28
07-14 18:16:21.477 D/dalvikvm(14115): Shared lib '/data/app-lib/com.google.android.gms-1/libgmscore.so' already loaded in same CL 0x4470dc28
07-14 18:16:21.477 D/dalvikvm(14115): Trying to load lib /data/app-lib/com.google.android.gms-1/libconscrypt_gmscore_jni.so 0x4470dc28
07-14 18:16:21.477 D/dalvikvm(14115): Shared lib '/data/app-lib/com.google.android.gms-1/libconscrypt_gmscore_jni.so' already loaded in same CL 0x4470dc28
```

SuperActivity.java:84

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
```

DashActivity.java:208

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
```

At this stage I have no idea where to look or what exactly this means. I have tried adding `vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true` in my gradle file with no luck

I am using `gradle:3.0.0-alpha6`, also, DashActivity is extending SuperActivity

Comment: what version of gradle are using ?

Comment: @OussemaAroua gradle:3.0.0-alpha6

Answer (score 0):

Set `android.enableAapt2=false` in `gradle.properties`

See: [Stop working project with vector drawables after update build.gradle on API < 21](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45056756/stop-working-project-with-vector-drawables-after-update-build-gradle-on-api-21)

Comment: Thank you, however Issue dissapeared when I downgraded gradle from 3.0.0-alpha6 to 2.3.3

Comment: The issue is connected to the alpha version of gradle 3, so downgrading is one of the possible ways. However, if you wish to stay on gradle 3, turning aapt2 off should help

Comment: Thank you for that, I will give it a try and revert back.